# Configure git to do diff on commit against files with a different name pattern using flyway

Tags: git, postgresql, flyway

We use git to manage our code repositories.

One of our repositories is a database migration repository that uses `flywaydb`.

Databases have state over time, and object dependencies, so best practices for use of flyway is to have incrementing file prefixes using either timestamps or numbers, and then the script name.  This way files are listed alphabetically (chronologically) and executed sequentially by `flyway` which tracks the state of what last script was run, and can run the missing scripts.

The problem is when files are named sequentially over time, and they replace the same database object such as a database view, how can we configure either git or flyway such that at the time of the commit, git is smart enough to do the file difference against a file with a different name based on a pattern and not a previous version of that file?

For example, I create a view, and someone updates that view a few days later... it will require two files such as:

```
V20181121131512__create_myview.sql
V20181126235217__replace_myview.sql
```

In each view, we CREATE or REPLACE a view and just update it. I would like to know if there is any way that git can be configured to do it's diff on commit against a file naming pattern. For example, the suffix, which will be for the same database object name.

I don't want to do manual diffs all the time when there are a lot of pull requests to review, and I want to quickly see what changed between different developers commits to speed up my review time. But the sequential naming for database state over time forces the previous code for a database object into a different file, so every commit for the same database object like a `SQL` view "appears" to be a brand new file and there is no history to compare it to.

Any thoughts on how to approach this? Can git be configured to do diff's on commit against a file naming suffix pattern? Or, is there another alternative to structuring the repo and file naming of flyway files such that database state over time can be addressed?

Comment: is that text or binary data that are held by your files?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this issue altogether by switching to [Flyway repeatable migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#repeatable-migrations) for all long lived objects that do not directly hold data.

They allow you to keep the history of your view in the same file in Git. Flyway will automatically reapply it whenever its checksum changes.

Comment: Thanks for that Axel, I haven't considered the repeatable migrations flyway versioning for some of those files... But for things like views that have dependencies on tables being created, how does it address that if the tables need to be created at a specific point in time before the view?  It's good to be able to track the view after the fact with a single migration script, but I'm not sure how this gets around the required a-priori state, even if a-posteriori, a single file would be sufficient to manage the object?

Comment: @Mark: I don't use Flyway but with Liquibase and Postgres we have one script at the beginning that is always executed and just drops all views in the database. Then we can change any table without having to cope with dependencies between views and tables. And after all the "table" migrations, we simply re-run all view definitions again.

Comment: @Mark Repeatable migrations are always executed after versioned ones (which you should use to create your tables)